# Правильно ли записывать в файл через функцию таким образом?

Tags: c, файлы

*На смысл данной программы не обращать внимания, приведено лишь для примера. Интересует только запись в файл через функцию*

http://ideone.com/KBnfBW

Если что-то неправильно, укажите на недочёты, пожалуйста.

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос.

Вас интересует, можно ли вызвать функцию с параметром типа `FILE *`, чтобы она записала что-то в переданный файл?

Да, можно.

Недочеты. По крайней мере:

1. Надо проверять успешно ли открыт файл.

2. При нормальном завершении заканчиваете программу `return 0;` (или `exit(0);`).

Comment: >Вас интересует, можно ли вызвать функцию с параметром типа FILE *, чтобы она записала что-то в переданный файл?
Именно.
>Надо проверять успешно ли открыт файл.
Можно поподробнее?
Проверять в ф-и head (на данном примере)? Или в main?
>При нормальном завершении заканчиваете программу return 0; (или exit(0);).
Да, про это знаю, но пока (почему-то) сказали писать без этого.

Comment: Проверьте в main. Для Вашего кода напишите, например:

    ...
    if (!(f = fopen("000.txt", "w")) {
      perror("output file");
      exit(1);
    }
    ...

Вместо

    ...
    f = fopen("000.txt", "w");
    ... 

Только идея использовать такую функцию (без параметров) не слишком хорошая. Вам придется все записываемые данные делать глобальными, а к этому лучше не привыкать.

--

И еще. Если есть такая возможность, то сразу начинайте программировать в \*nix (например, в Linux).

Намучиться с виндой еще успеете.

Comment: >Проверьте в main. Для Вашего кода напишите, например

Благодарю.

>Только идея использовать такую функцию (без параметров) не слишком хорошая. Вам придется все записываемые данные делать глобальными, а к этому лучше не привыкать.

А можно здесь тоже поподробнее?
Имеется ввиду функция main?

>И еще. Если есть такая возможность, то сразу начинайте программировать в *nix (например, в Linux).
Намучиться с виндой еще успеете.

В том и проблема, что нет возможности, точнее сказать, в универе нужно под win (а если ещё точнее, под dos). Для своего опыта писать под *nix проблем нет.

Comment: @froxxendsg, имеются в виду глобальные (или extern) данные, которые видны и в `main()` и в других функциях. Их надо описывать вне тела функции.

Конечно, для программы из полусотни строк в одном-двух файлах это не принципиально. Скорей всего не запутаетесь. 

А вот когда программа состоит из тысяч строк в десятках файлов, то начинаются проблемы с пониманием, какая часть кода какие  глобальные переменные использует.

А Вы в книжках про это еще не читали?

Comment: @froxxendsg,в случаях подобных вашему основному вопросу, лучше напишите пару десятков строчек, которые просто проверяют ваше предположение относительно поведения и работы какой-либо функции. Прогоните программу под отладчиком. Таким образом вы получите больше опыта и информацию, подтвержденную практикой.

Comment: @avp, я про то, что про какую функцию без параметров говорится в моём примере (без параметров только `main()`, но при чём тут глобальные данные?).
Или, возможно, я что-то не так понял.

Про сами глобальные данные, естественно, знаю. (но пока не приходилось их использовать)

------------------
@glacier, спасибо, учту. Просто нужно было знать, правильно ли так передавать параметр. (бывают случаи, когда программа работает правильно, но сам способ реализации - неправильный)

Comment: @froxxendsg, действительно, в `head()` есть параметр. Я имел в виду данные, которые `head()` будет писать в файл.

Они в Вашей программе будут действительно глобальным (если вытащить `head()` в отдельный файл) или могут быть статическими в файле с `main()`, `head()` и м.б. другими функциями, обрабатывающими это данные.

Вот это я имел в виду, когда говорил о глобальных данных. Надеюсь прояснил свою мысль.

Comment: >Я имел в виду данные, которые head() будет писать в файл.

Данные будут передаваться через параметры функции `head()`, просто в данном примере решил их опустить (дабы оставить только суть вопроса).
Да, спасибо, теперь мне ваша мысль стала ясна.
-------------------
(Не думал, что есть ограничение по кол-ву комментариев..)

Comment: @avp: на тему нашего обсуждения в комментариях: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/216289/6802